# Why am I getting different types in strings?

Tags: string, go, byte, rune

I have encountered a situation that I do not understand.

```
    a := "hello"
    fmt.Printf("%v %T\n",a[0],a[0])
```

This gives `104 uint8`.

```
    for _,v := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%v %T\n",v,v)
    }
```

This gives `104 int32` for the first iteration. I don't understand why their types are not same. First one is `byte`, second one is `rune`. I expect both to be `byte`.

Comment: `a` is a string and not a slice of byte. And that's how `for` loops over strings work. If there wasn't a special rule for strings you couldn't range over strings at all as these are neither arrays, slices nor channels.

Answer (score 3):

This might explain it:

https://blog.golang.org/strings

In short: if `a` is a string, `a[i]` is a byte, but here, `r` is a `rune`:

```
for _,r:=range a {
...
}
```

When you range over a string, you range over the runes of that string. To range over the bytes of a string, use:

```
for i:=0;i<len(a);i++ {
   // Here, a[i] is byte
}
```

Comment: And a single rune can take up to 4-bytes (32-bits): https://play.golang.org/p/kmWjgfP4NAT